# ESXi/vSphere how to create nic team

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I have essentially zero experience with ESXi/vSphere, sorry in advance if this may sounds obvious for some of you. I have installed ESXi/vSphere 7 on my server and I need to set up a nic team with the 2 10Gb adapters.
I have to do this from console, because I cannot access vSphere until I create the team and configure it. This is because the switch is configured with bonding+LACP, and the static IP address I got is on one of the two adapters (wmnic5). Online I could only find the procedure via the vSphere, nothing from ESXi command line.

How do I do this?

1)create the team from wmnic5 and wmnic6

2)configure the IP, submask, gateway, and dns server

3)configure LACP (dynamic)

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you can configure the ESXi to use bonding via the menu on the console, but you can't configure the bonding mode there.

In my experience the easiest way is to pull one cable, configure the bonding for the management interface via the web UI and then reconnect the cable.

Comment: unfortunately it did not work, I had to use a spare 1Gb port to make it work.